# C++ Embedded PyTorch GPU Inference Leaks Memory

Tags: c++, pytorch, memory-leaks, cpython

I have a C++ program which runs a Python script using CPython interface, doing GPU-based inference using PyTorch.

PyTorch may fail due to lack of memory (which is fine by be), but after the failure, I want the C++ code to continue to run, and all the GPU memory used by PyTorch to be freed.

What I tried (in Python, at `except` namespace after OOM crash, or in C++ after catching the raise) -

**Python**

- `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`
- `self.net_ = None; <all_tensors> = None; gc.collect()`
- printing available device memory with `torch.cuda.memory_allocated` and `torch.cuda.memory_reserved` before and after the freeing attempy, had no change

**C++**

- `Py_Finalize()`
- `Py_XDECREF(<python module PyObject*>)`

and other suggestion I found online. None of them seem to release the allocated memory, which remains until the C++ program finishes.

I am using Python3.9, and PyTorch 1.13.0. I saw an issue regarding memory leaks by `Py_Finalize()` which was solved in Python3.11, but it doesn't seem related, from what I looked at.

Any tips or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this will resolve your issue but you might at least want `del self.net_` (and have that come before the empty_cache call).

Comment: I tried all such possible combinations, none seem to release the memory. Doing `self.net_.detach().cpu()` and then `del self.net_; gc.collect()` did bring back a few dozen MBs, but all of the intermediate gradients remained allocated on the GPU unfortunately (~2GB).

Comment: What you want is to more or less completely "deinitialize" CUDA, which I don't think is possible. Once PyTorch sets up the CUDA environment, it will only take it down if the whole process is taken down. Is there any particular reason you want/have to use Python ? If not, I would maybe give TensorRT a shot, you might have more control over the memory there.

Comment: Why not use C++ with fork() in a while loop to separately running the python script in a different process, and let the process finish once pytorch goes out of GPU memory? Let the OS releases the memory. Once the process finishes, fork() creates a new pytorch process.

Comment: 1 Thank you both for the comments! I will provide some more context - My C++ program uses the GPU as well for some image processing, and one of the processing steps is a DL filter, which is implemented by a Python script, the C++ uses CUDA as well. In order to boost performance of the C++ code, I use caching mechanism for certain stuff, thus free GPU memory is highly valuable, and should be released if possible. The C++ calls the Python script not as a separate process, but directly using the Python C API, and it transfers the device image on the RAM and not on the disk (which saves a lot of

Comment: 2 time). Therefore I cannot use forks (i.e., several Python processes), unless you have some other concrete suggestion to transfer memory on the RAM (I am not aware of one). Regarding the PyTorch library, I agree that I can use other ones, trying LibTorch (the PyTorch C++ version) didn't boost running times so I decided to keep it in Python, since the DL model is handled by some non C++ programmers in my organization. 
In short, my goal is to free the memory PyTorch uses on the GPU (to accelerate other computations, and for some other features like "pause" my program has) if the filter fails.